# Upload File using Angular JS is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just followed the way mentioned in this article to upload a file https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm  link:

```
function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                console.log("len:"+element[0].files);
               modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
                console.log("filenames:"+element[0].files);
            });
        });
```

Here when I debug the element does not contain any attributes called files, so I always getting it as undefined.  I have tried many different ways, all resulted with the same issue.  How to solve this issue?  Why element doesn't have files attributes?

Answer (score 0):

My File upload directive code

```
  module.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And usage code

```
<input class="import-export-hide-fileinput" type="file" id="file" file-model="ctrl.fileToImport" name="file"
                   accept="undefined">
```

Serivce calling

```
mySerice.importReports(self.fileToImport)
                        .then(self.onImportSuccess, self.onError);
```

Service code

```
importReports: function (fileInput) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', fileInput);
            return $http.post('/path/import', fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.upload= function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

    r.onloadend = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      //send your binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

Hope It helps..!